# How to unselect all selected items in RecyclerView's SelectionTracker even if some items are scrolled off the screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx, multi-select

I am using SelectionTracker to implement a multiple selection RecyclerView. the select/unselect feature works as expected if I do it manually (Item is on the screen and I change its state by tapping) but if I try to unselect all items, some of which are off screen, using clearSelection method of selection tracker it only unselects the items which are currently visible on the screen.

**This is how I am building the SelectionTracker**

```
tracker = SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(
            "mySelection",
            recyclerView,
            MyKeyProvider(recyclerView),
            MyItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
            StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
        ).withSelectionPredicate(
            SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()
        ).build()
recyclerAdapter.tracker = tracker
```

**Following is `bindItem` and `onBindViewHolder` methods of `ViewHolder` and `adapter` respectively**

```
fun bindItems(model: Model, isActivated: Boolean) {
    itemView.isActivated = isActivated
    if(itemView.isActivated){
         /* Do something */
    }
    else{
        /* Do something */
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
     val number = displayList[position]
     tracker?.let {
            holder.bindItems(number, it.isSelected(position.toLong()))
     }
}
```

**I call the clear selection method on click of a menu item**

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    if((selectionMode) && (item?.itemId==android.R.id.home)){
        tracker.clearSelection()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Edit: This seems to be a bug in the Library, I have encountered the same issue while using the Android Gmail app, Which I think must be using SelectionTracker

Comment: How do you store which items are selected or not ?

Comment: I don't store that information, I think that is the responsibility of SelectionTracker class

Comment: Did you try something like `tracker.setItemsSelected(tracker.getSelection(), false)`

Comment: @cesarmarch This doesn't help, I have the same problem.

Comment: For me, this looks like a library bug. I can propose you for fast solution, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `tracker.clearSelection()`

Answer (score -1):

You add a listener to the tracker, which when changing the state of any element, checks if it was the last selected element and updates the entire list if this is true

```
tracker?.addObserver(object : SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver<Long>() {
        override fun onItemStateChanged(key: Long, selected: Boolean) {
            if(!tracker!!.hasSelection())
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            super.onItemStateChanged(key, !selected)

        }
    })
```

Comment: Cna you explain your answer? this code wont run on the machine until the user undestands how to use it.

Comment: super.onItemStateChanged(key, !selected) is misleading...  called function is empty in SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver...