# Recycler View Not Deselecting When View Is Hidden

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view that displays four numbers. 1,2,3,4. When I select any of those numbers, everything seems fine. The problem is when I Horizontally scroll and the other numbers populate my screen: 4,5,6,7.

[image]

**State 1**

[image]

**State2**

In this example, scrolling back and forth between **State 1** and **State 2**, 7 and 1 are both selected when only one of them should be selected

> **Question**: How can I make it so that clicking one of the numbers deselects the number that isn't visible on screen?

**Adapter:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private String[] days;
private String[] numbers;
SelectionTracker<Long> mSelectionTracker;
private static MyAdapter myAdapter;


public MyAdapter(String[] day, String[] number){
    days = day;
    numbers = number;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}


//Set Keys
public void setSelectionTracker(SelectionTracker<Long> selectionTracker) {
    mSelectionTracker = selectionTracker;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String dayInit = days[position];
    String numberInit = numbers[position];
    Long id = getItemId(position);


    boolean isSelected = false;
    if(mSelectionTracker != null) {
        if (mSelectionTracker.isSelected(id)) {
            isSelected = true;
        }
    }


    holder.bind(position, id, dayInit, numberInit, isSelected);
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView dayView, numberView;
    public View view;
    ScheduleDetails scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetails();

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        dayView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day);
        numberView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day_number);

    }

    void bind(int position, Long key, String dayInit, String numberInit, Boolean isSelected){
        scheduleDetails.position = position;
        scheduleDetails.identifier = key;

        System.out.println("Check: " + position);

        dayView.setText(dayInit);
        numberView.setText(numberInit);
        view.setActivated(isSelected);
    }


    public ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails(@NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent){
        return scheduleDetails;
    }
}

static class ScheduleDetails extends ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>{
    int position;
    Long identifier;

    @Override
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Long getSelectionKey() { return identifier; }

    @Override
    public boolean inSelectionHotspot(@NonNull MotionEvent e){
        return true;
    }
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return vh;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return days.length;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

Comment: This seems a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585352/how-to-unselect-all-selected-items-in-recyclerviews-selectiontracker-even-if-so - Have you tried the solution proposed there?

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`onViewRecycled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewRecycled(VH)) method in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` class and disable the view there. Here's an example based on the code you've provided:

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder) {
    //disable activated view when it got recycle
    holder.view.setActivated(false)
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

Now each time the view is being recycled, you deselect it, and when this view is bound again (in your `bind` method of `MyViewHolder` class), you are selecting only the correct view.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks though

Comment: A complete solution would have to re-select the item on onBindViewHolder; maybe keeping a separate list of offscreen selected items. Or maybe a cleaner implementation is possible using the SelectionTracker itself?